# Provide multiple email recepients in python script

Tags: python, email

I am using python email program which works find when I have 1 recepient BUT fails when I have 2.

Could someone please help me to resolve the issue?

Here's the code:

```
#Create the container (outer) email message.
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = subject
me = "user1@com"
recepient = "user1@hotmailcom;user2@hotmail.com"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = ''.join(recepient)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Email recipients must be *comma* separated, not using a semi-colon; that is just a Microsoft convention:

```
recepient = "user1@hotmailcom,user2@hotmail.com"
msg['To'] = recepient
```

You don't need to use `str.join()` when you already have *one* string.

If you have a list of recipients, then using `str.join()` would make sense:

```
recepients = ["user1@hotmailcom", "user2@hotmail.com"]
msg['To'] = ', '.join(recepients)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the semicolon with a comma:

```
recipient = "user1@hotmailcom;user2@hotmail.com"
msg['To'] = recipient.replace(';', ', ')
```

[The docs have examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) which show the addresses should be comma-separated:

```
COMMASPACE = ', '
# family = the list of all recipients' email addresses
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(family)
```